# How to get group number in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have a use case where I want to assign a unique increasing partition number to each partition when using a window query in postgres.

For example, I want to get an output like this:

```
Partition Key | Row_Num() | Partition Number  
Apple         | 1         | 1
Apple         | 2         | 1
Oranges       | 1         | 2
Oranges       | 2         | 2
Pear          | 1         | 3
Pear          | 2         | 3
```

Basically, apart from row_num() which gives us unique value within each "window", I want to have a number which is unique for each "window"
How do I achieve this ? Is there any built in function in postgres for this ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
select partitionkey,
       row_number() over (partition by partitionkey order by partitionkey) as row_num,
       dense_rank() over (order by partitionkey) as partition_number
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works for me. Been trying to solve this problem since a long time.

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for `dense_rank()`

```
. . .
dense_rank() over (order by PartitionKey) as number
```

Comment: Dense rank doesn't work in this case. It won't give a unique value for each partition.

Comment: Yes, It is working. Thanks! Accepting the other answer, as it was a few seconds faster, and I can't think of any other criteria.